# SCP (Simple Configurable Products) and Product Reviews

Tags: review

I have a working shop system with installed SCP. Whenever I want write a new product review, I get the error message:

> Please specify the product's option(s).

As I can see, the action for the review form links to this target:

```
/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3MtcGFzc3QuZGUvaW5kZXgucGhwL3Jldmlldy9wcm9kdWN0L2xpc3QvaWQvMzE5Lw,,/product/319/form_key/QmbYaUx9H2Pfyhfa/
```

But it should link to this target:

```
/review/product/post/id/<product_id>/
```

It seems that there is missing a form element for the review.

I tried to modify the file:

> \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review\form.phtml

But any changes in the  tag are useless and disappear...

Comment: Are you sure you use the base/default theme ? When you say the changes disappear, do you mean they disappear from the file ?! Or they don't appear on frontend ?

Comment: Well I'm not using the default theme, but the theme i'm using has no template for review. They don't appear in the frontend. Or are there other files I could modify?

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty weird (and so, hard to debug). If you request the page without javascript, is the DOM the same ? what does the log shows if you add a "Mage::log(get_class($this));" at the first line of \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review\form.phtml and then clear the cache ?

Comment: I disabled JS, the DOM seems to be the same. The get_class says: Mage_Review_Block_Form. But it's strange. When I use Chrome's "inspect element", the form tag is missing, when I use "view source", the form tag is there: <form action="/review/product/post/id/319/" method="post" id="review-form">

Comment: Oh now I see the error: the **review form tag** is _inside_ the **add-to-cart form**. What a mess... Seems like I have to modify my layout file, do I?

Comment: Yep. Or you can check that your add-to-cart **<form></form>** is well closed.